# Curry-Howard correspondence in CIC/propositional logic?

Tags: type-theory

I am trying to understand how the type theory of the COQ theorem prover (calculus of constructions or CIC) works. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_constructions) states that it can be considered an extension of the Curry-Howard isomorphism.

For constructive propositional logic the Curry-Howard isomorphism states that types can be seen as propositions, and proofs as programs. For types/propositions $A,B$, propositions can be viewed as types in the following way (propositions on the left, types on the right, $\Leftrightarrow$ denoting correspondence)

$$A\rightarrow B \Leftrightarrow A\Rightarrow B$$
$$A\land B \Leftrightarrow A\times B$$
$$A\lor B\Leftrightarrow A+B$$

Then, for example, proving that

$$\forall A\forall B: A\rightarrow A\lor B,$$
where $A,B$ are interpreted as types can be seen as a proof that for any types $A,B$, the type $A\Rightarrow A+B$ exists. Proof of this fact can be converted into program and vice versa. In this case the program would simply return an $x\in A$, e.g. the left side of the pair, thereby showing the type exists.

Ok, so now to the question. CIC implements a predicate logic. How are the terms $\forall x: A.B$, $\lambda x: A.B$ interpreted in the correspondence? An example would be fine. Keep in mind I am very new to this $\lambda$ notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall x: A.B$ is a type. It is interpreted as a terminating algorithm that takes in an $A$ and produces a $B$ as a result.

Under the Curry-Howard correspondence we interpret this as the logical statement that A implies B.

---

$\lambda x: A. M$ is a function. It takes an input $x$ of type $A$ and returns $M$ (which might reference $x$).

Under the Curry-Howard correspondence this is interpreted as a proof of $A$ implies $B$ (when $M$ has type $B$)..

Comment: Is there a chance you could give an example of some proposition regarding naturals for example?